# To_CHAR(SYSDATE, ...) ----> TO_DATE

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, to-date, to-char

So i have this code :

```
create or replace TRIGGER tr_after_logon
AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA

DECLARE

var_date VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN

SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD:MM:YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  INTO var_date FROM DUAL ;

  INSERT INTO activity_log (numero, idsession, action, detail, objet, quand) 

 VALUES (seq_activity.nextval, USERENV('SESSIONID'), 'CONNEXION', ORA_DATABASE_NAME,
  ORA_CLIENT_IP_ADDRESS, TO_DATE(var_date, 'DD:MM:YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

END;
```

I get the ORA-01830 Error - because i can't convert my CHAR in DATE format right ? I don't manage to solve this problem

Thx for you help in advance !

Comment: What if you try this date format? `dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi PM`

Comment: Is that the entire code? If so, why can't you use a `date` variable, with no cast?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem so I assume you're not showing us your real code.

Comment: What does the entire error stack show - can you add that to the question? Is there a trigger on activity_log, perhaps? What data type is `quand`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a problem with your code, assuming `quand` is of type `date`, but why not just do this?

```
create or replace TRIGGER tr_after_logon
AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA

BEGIN

  INSERT INTO activity_log (numero, idsession, action, detail, objet, quand) 

 VALUES (seq_activity.nextval, USERENV('SESSIONID'), 'CONNEXION', ORA_DATABASE_NAME,
  ORA_CLIENT_IP_ADDRESS, SYSDATE);

END;
```

Comment: yes you're right 'quand' is of type 'date' ! I know it just work fine with the SYSDATE but I wanted to add the hour:minutes:seconds to my sysdate so that I had better tracability instead of just the date of the day

Comment: @YannickBerger - then you don't understand how dates work in Oracle. If you insert SYSDATE then you get exactly the same value and precision as with your conversion to string and back - where else would the hh:mi:ss be coming from? You just need to specify the format mask when you query your activity table.

Comment: @YannickBerger You clearly don't understand Oracle `date` data type. Please help yourself and read e.g. [DATE Data Type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref152).

Comment: @YannickBerger - in Oracle DATE values contain the fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. I know the name of the type is DATE, but they're really more of a timestamp-ish kind of thing. Converting a date to a character string doesn't magically add hours:minutes:seconds - they're already there. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis Indeed... I didn't see things like this but it make sense now :) thanks for your help (all of you)